# How to use NavigationRailView with Navigation Components in Kotlin

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack, material-components-android

I am using BottomNavigationView with Navigation Components like below:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        ---------
    >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_history_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/historyNavHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_history" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActiviy.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy {
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.historyNavHost) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupToolbar()

        binding.navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

And it works fine. But I want to use NavigationRailView instead of BottomNavigationView in the landscape layout of activity_main.xml. After changing it,

```
binding.navigaitonRailView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

the above line throws this error

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
```

How can I use NavigationRailView whit NavConroller?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need NavigationUI and navController as well

```
val navigationRailView = binding.navigationRail
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
        navigationRailView,
        navController
    )
```